# Dataframe performance issue while retrieving rows in hierarchy order in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

**Dataframe performance issue while retrieving rows in hierarchy order in pyspark.**

dataframe performance issue while retrieving  rows in hierarchy order in pyspark

I am trying to retrieve data in hierachy order using pyspark dataframe from a csv file but it is taking more than 3 hrs to retrieve 30k records in hierachy order.

is there any alternate way to solve this problem in pyspark dataframe?

can anyone please help me on this?

```
from datetime import datetime
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
    df = sc.read.csv(path/of/csv/file, **kargs)
    df.cache()
    df.show()

    def get_child(pid, df, col_name):
       df_child_s = df.selectExpr(col_name).where(col("pid") == pid)
       return df_child_s


    def all_data(pid, df, col_name):
       df_child_exist = True
       cnt = 0
       df_o = get_child_str(pid, df, col_name)

       df_o = df_o.withColumn("order_id", lit(cnt))

       df_child_exist = len(df_o.take(1)) >= 1
       if df_child_exist :
           dst = df_o.selectExpr("child_id").first()[0]

       while df_child_exist:
           cnt += 1


           df_o2 = get_child_str(dst, df, "*")
           df_o2 = df_o2.withColumn("order_id", lit(cnt))

           df_child_exist = len(df_o2.take(1)) >= 1
           if df_child_exist :

               dst = df_o2.selectExpr("childid_id").first()[0]
               df_o = df_o.union(df_o2)

       return df_o



    pid = 0
    start = datetime.now()
    df_f_1 = all_data(pid, df, "*")
    df_f_1.show()
    end = datetime.now()
    totalTime = end - start
    print(f"total execution time :{totalTime}")
```

**csv file data**    

childid    parentid
248278    264543
251713    252689
252689    248278
258977    251713
264543    0

**expected output result:**    

childId     parentId    
264543       0
248278       264543
252689       248278
251713       252689

    OR
+------+------+-------+
|   dst|   src|level|
+------+------+-------+
|264543|     0|      0|
|248278|264543|      1|
|252689|248278|      2|
|251713|252689|      3|
|258977|251713|      4||
+------+------+-------+

Comment: For hierarchical data it would be more natural to store the data in a hierarchical format such as json and use that for the file to read into your dataframe.  Spark is made for just this kind of data.  Tablular formats are awkward for hierarchies, especially ragged ones.  For a different approach you could try using GraphFrames instead of dataframes.  Not putting this as an answer as these suggestions are too far from your question.  Let us know if there is some reason you must use csv for your hierarchy.

Comment: our data is in csv format and the data is not in order but each row is connected with each other in parent child relationship.  My requirement is to order the data in hierarchy order.   To resolve this I have written this in dataframe but  again it is creating performance issue.  I am not good in graphFrame . can you please help me to provide pyspark graphframe examples to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj, Here is my graphFrame answer as requested.

I thought there was a simpler way to do this with GraphFrames.  I didn't find a way to find all decedents in a trivial way.  I provide two solutions.

```
from graphframes import GraphFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# initial dataframe
edgesDf = spark.createDataFrame([
    (248278, 264543),
    (251713, 252689),
    (252689, 248278),
    (258977, 251713),
    (264543, 0)
  ],
  ["dst", "src"]
)

# get all ids as vertices
verticesDf = edgesDf.select(col("dst").alias("id")).union(edgesDf.select("src")).distinct()

# create graphFrame
graphGf = GraphFrame(verticesDf, edgesDf)

# for performance
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoints")
graphGf.cache()

####  Motif approach
# note that this requires knowing the depth of the tree
fullPathDf = graphGf.find("(a)-[ab]->(b); (b)-[bc]->(c); (c)-[cd]->(d); (d)-[de]->(e); (e)-[ef]->(f)")

# pivot
edgeDf = fullPathDf.select(col("ab").alias("edge")).union(fullPathDf.select("bc")).union(fullPathDf.select("cd")).union(fullPathDf.select("de")).union(fullPathDf.select("ef"))

# Result 
edgeDf.select("edge.dst", "edge.src").show()

### Breadth First Search approach
# 
# Does not require knowing the depth, but does require knowing the id of the leaf node
pathDf = graphGf.bfs("id = 0", "id = 258977", maxPathLength = 5)

# pivot
edgeDf = pathDf.select(col("e0").alias("edge")).union(pathDf.select("e1")).union(pathDf.select("e2")).union(pathDf.select("e3")).union(pathDf.select("e4")

#
edgeDf.select("edge.dst", "edge.src").show()
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your inputs..Regarding Motif approach how long i have to create path like this: (a)-[ab]->(b); (b)-[bc]->(c); (c)-[cd]->(d); (d)-[de]->(e); (e)-[ef]->(f), because I have more than 30k data and regarding Breadth First Search approach i does not know the id of last leaf because all my data will be unordered.  if i  do motif search till (a)->[ab]->b;(b)->(bc)->(c) level then can you please suggest how i do unoin to get data in sorted and also can i get extra column which can be used as reference for sorting

Comment: Your concerns are serious limitation of my two solutions.  I did not find a better way.  As I say, I thought there was a way to get all decedents, but I didn't find it.  Regarding a sort column I think you would need to do that after you get the back to dataframes as a result.  Now that I understand more about what you are trying to do I see that graphframes may not be a good fit.  They may be both too powerful ( not meant for a simple hierarchy, but for richly interconnected data ) and too immature of an API still ( why no "get all decedents?  Am I missing it? )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a dataframe checkpoint() to your code.  This prevents the dataframe lineage from getting too long and causing performance issues.  You code seems to have a number of dataframes, it is not clear to me why you are creating multiple dataframes so I'm not sure which dataframes would benefit from checkpointing. Add checkpoints to dataframes that you modify in every iteration.  [Here](https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-dataframe-basics/) is a nice pyspark explaination of checkpointing

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I will check you suggested link mentioned above(about checkpoint).  can you please  review and  optimise my code mentioned above. or is there way to write code in python and convert in pyspark dataframe to parallelise. i am not sure how to do? can you please guide me?  and can you  please also suggest where to use checkpoint in my code.